# Display Frontend Category URL in Backend Magento

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.2, magento2.1

Hi how can I retrieve the value of a category url in the backend? I'm expecting the url value to be equivalent to the url in the frontend and NOT the url in the backend. Is there a way to achieve this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer for this. The solution is to use an App/Emulator that is available in Magento. The idea is to start the emulation before you execute the Frontend Catgory URL retrieval that you want and close the emulation when its done.

Here are the links on how to implement it [App Emulation](https://www.hexbrain.com/blog/product-view-button-simple-module). Didn't know it was this simple to solve the issue. Below is how my code looks like

```
class MenuCategory extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

    public function getStoreCategories($storeManager, $emulator)
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $emulator->startEnvironmentEmulation(null, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
        $categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStore($storeManager->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq' => 2))
            ->addIsActiveFilter()
            ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc'); 

        foreach ($categories as $category) {    
            echo $category->getUrl() . " - " . $category->getUrl() . "\n";

        }

        $emulator->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
        return $content;
    }
}
```

So the idea here is to instantiate the emulator and make magento think that you are going to modify or perform like you are in the frontend hence the code **\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND** when you close the environment emulation it will go back to how it was whether you are in adminhtml or frontend

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the category url you need to use the `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository` function `getUrl()` like so:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$emulator->startEnvironmentEmulation(null, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStore($storeManager->getStore())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq' => 2))
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc'); 

foreach ($categories as $category) {    
    $categoryObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository')->get($category->getId());
    echo $categoryObject->getUrl()."\n";
}
```

Comment: Already tried this and this will display the category url based on the view. If its in storeview it will generate a url store category url. but when on admin it will generate a category url for admin

Comment: the one on top is the code I'm using. I placed the code in my Model Repository

Comment: you are using `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory` class which is collection class using that you can not get URL, you have to load single category using `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository` and then you will get category URL.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean but I was able to retrieve all the categories using this code. The collection will return multiple categories. I then loop through all available categories and display it

Comment: I have updated my code you can use that in your function.

Comment: thanks for the effort really appreciate it. But my code above already retrieving the category and you don't have to instantiate the categoryrepository

Comment: when you are load collection then it only supplies necessary information due to optimizing solution. if you wan those detail which is not passed in a collection then you have to load category.
I have checked this code in my local system, it's working fine. there is no issue.